# Putting thing (moving) inside struct gives lifetime error

Tags: rust

First of all, I know it's much better to create minimal reproducible examples, but I don't have idea on where this problem comes from. I've cleared much of the code for this question.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Item<'a, 'b: 'a> {
    socket: Socket<'a, 'b>,
    refs:   usize
}
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct SocketSet<'a, 'b: 'a, 'c: 'a + 'b> {
    sockets: ManagedSlice<'a, Option<Item<'b, 'c>>>
}

impl<'a, 'b: 'a, 'c: 'a + 'b> SocketSet<'a, 'b, 'c> {
    pub fn new<SocketsT>(sockets: SocketsT) -> SocketSet<'a, 'b, 'c>
            where SocketsT: Into<ManagedSlice<'a, Option<Item<'b, 'c>>>> {
        let sockets = sockets.into();
        Set {
            sockets: sockets
        }
    }

pub struct TunSmolStack<'a, 'b, 'c> {
    sockets: SocketSet<'a, 'b, 'c>,
}

impl<'a, 'b, 'c> TunSmolStack<'a, 'b, 'c> {
    pub fn new(interface_name: String) -> Result<TunSmolStack<'a, 'b, 'c>, u32> {
        let socket_set = SocketSet::new(vec![]);
        Ok(TunSmolStack{
            sockets: socket_set,
        })
    }
```

Here's the full error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'b` due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/virtual_tun/smol_stack.rs:26:12
   |
26 |         Ok(TunSmolStack{
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime `'b` as defined on the impl at 16:10...
  --> src/virtual_tun/smol_stack.rs:16:10
   |
16 | impl<'a, 'b, 'c> TunSmolStack<'a, 'b, 'c> {
   |          ^^
note: ...so that the expression is assignable
  --> src/virtual_tun/smol_stack.rs:26:12
   |
26 |           Ok(TunSmolStack{
   |  ____________^
28 | |             sockets: socket_set,
29 | |         })
   | |_________^
   = note: expected  `virtual_tun::smol_stack::TunSmolStack<'_, 'b, 'c>`
              found  `virtual_tun::smol_stack::TunSmolStack<'_, '_, '_>`
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the type `std::option::Option<virtual_tun::interface::smoltcp::socket::SocketSetItem<'_, '_>>` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/virtual_tun/smol_stack.rs:22:26
   |
22 |         let socket_set = SocketSet::new(vec![]);
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It is complaining about `SocketSet`. Ok, possibly something related to the inner objects of the `socket_set` not living enough? Why it talks about static lifetime?

PS: putting my mouse on top of `socket_set` on

```
let socket_set = SocketSet::new(vec![]);
```

gives this type for the variable:

```
virtual_tun::interface::smoltcp::socket::SocketSet<'a, 'static, 'static>
```

Well, the lifetime `'a` for the SocketSet, as defined here:

```
    pub struct SocketSet<'a, 'b: 'a, 'c: 'a + 'b> {
        sockets: ManagedSlice<'a, Option<Item<'b, 'c>>>
    }
```

is the lifetime of the thing stored inside `ManagedSlice`, which is `Option<Item<'b, 'c>>`

So, the anonymous `vec` that I pass to the constructor of `SocketSet` is converted into a reference to slice with lifetime `'a`, and the things inside the slice have `static` lifetime. Don't know why, but they have. I guess the problem is that it requires that `'b` from `SmolStack` should be `'static`?

**ps: I don't have control over SocketSet, SocketSet::new, etc...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because of the lifetime constraint on `sockets` in `SocketSet::new`. `ManagedSlice` Requires that its value to live as long as `'a` [seen in its definition](https://docs.rs/managed/0.7.1/managed/enum.ManagedSlice.html) `ManagedSlice<'a, T: 'a>`.

The generic constraint `SocketsT: Into<ManagedSlice<'a, Option<Item<'b, 'c>>>` does not assert that the `ManagedSlice` is `Owned`. So the compiler will make sure that this code works regardless if the `into` returns a `Owned` or `Borrowed`. `ManagedSlice` has to live for the longest lifetime of `ManagedSlice::Owned` and `ManagedSlice::Borrowed` because it could be either.

Calling `.into()` on `sockets` does creates a `ManagedSlice::Owned` in this case, but in a situation where `into` returned `ManagedSlice::Borrowed`, `into` would create a reference. So it makes `'a` at least as long as `'static`, as `sockets` is owned by the function and `a` is a reference to `sockets`.

Changing the generic constraints to make it clear that what is being passed in is not a reference gets rid of the warning.

```
impl<'a, 'b: 'a, 'c: 'a + 'b> SocketSet<'a, 'b, 'c> {
    pub fn new<SocketsT>(sockets: SocketsT) -> SocketSet<'a, 'b, 'c>
            where SocketsT: Into<Vec<Option<Item<'b, 'c>>>> {
        SocketSet {
            sockets: ManagedSlice::Owned(sockets.into())
        }
    }
}
```

The error will re-emerge if you modify the code to

```
sockets: ManagedSlice::from(sockets.into())
```

Because again, it is not clear if `from` is going to return `Owned` or `Borrowed`.

You can also simplify a lot of the lifetimes away from your code to make it more readable.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Item<'a> {
    socket: Socket<'a, 'a>,
    refs:   usize
}
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct SocketSet<'a> {
    sockets: ManagedSlice<'a, Option<Item<'a>>>
}

impl<'a> SocketSet<'a> {
    pub fn new<SocketsT>(sockets: SocketsT) -> SocketSet<'a>
            where SocketsT: Into<Vec<Option<Item<'a>>>> {
        SocketSet {
            sockets: ManagedSlice::Owned(sockets.into())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on 2 things: why the error happens exactly? Since  `socket_set` has static lifetimes on the references it holds, so there's no problem putting then inside the struct. Also, what exactl is `&mut []`? Can I put things inside it? I need to put more sockets inside it on the future

Comment: And I cannot make those lifetime modifications because I don't have control over `SocketSet` and `Item`. I appreciate your suggestion though for learning

Comment: I've just seen that you modified the `new` argument. I can't do that also.

Comment: Im not sure you can fix this without modifying the `new` method.

The return type for the method `SocketSet<'a>`. So the `'a` lifetime must outlive the method.
`new` owns the `sockets: SocketsT` parameter that is passed in because it is not a refrence. 
`SocketsT` is a `Into<ManagedSlice<'a>>`.

So when calling `.into()`, it needs to turn the owned `sockets` parameter into a reference that outlives the method. So the reference must be static.

Comment: `&mut []` is a mutable reference to an empty slice, letting the compiler figure out what its contents is. Its the equivalent to `vec![]` but for a slice.

Comment: sorry I didnt undertand. There are 3 lifetimes. `'b, 'c` are static and live more than `'a`. `SocketSet::new` creates a new `SocketSet`. What are the 3 lifetimes of this `SocketSet`? I understand that initially the `new` function owns the data but it's moved to the `SocketSet` that is being returned

Comment: socket::set essentially returns `ManagedSlice<'a, Option<Item<'b, 'c>>>`. So, the lifetime `'a` is the lifetime of the reference to the `vec`, am I right? Well, why this lifetime isn't `'static`? The compiler knows `new` is just creating something and moving it

Comment: I started a bounty. Understanding the problem is more important for me than solving it. I want to understanding lifetimes on Rust and I'm having some difficulties

Comment: Hi @pigeonhands, I opened a bounty. Hope you can explain me better where the error is happening. Thank you!

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs i have edited my answer, I slightly misinterpreted the problem but the solution and reason for the error is the same. hopefully it explains it a bit better.

Comment: I understood everything in your explanation, but it's still not clear why `'a` being static is a problem. See, by definition, `'b` and `'c` need to live as long as `'a`, and we already saw that they're both `'static`. So `'a, 'b, 'c` are `'static`, where's the problem?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs The problem is `let socket_set = SocketSet::new(vec![]);` is creating a `SocketSet` instance bound to the `'a` lifetime. The `'a` lifetime is static. 

`socket_set ` is not static. So it will not live for as long as `'a` requires it to.

Comment: hmmm, the problem is that `socket_set` is being moved into `TunSmolStack`, therefore how can its lifetime have any meaning in this? It's just a temporary variable for putting inside the struct. In fact I tried `Ok(TunSmolStack {
            sockets: SocketSet::new(vec![]),
        })` and the same problem persists

Comment: Because `SocketSet::new` is being stored in a non-static variable, the compiler can not **guarantee** that the `SocketSet` it will live for `'static`.

Comment: then why doing `let socket_set: &'static SocketSet = &SocketSet::new(vec![]);` wont make the problem go away?

Comment: that creates a static **reference** to a `SocketSet` instance. The issue is with the `SocketSet` instance itself.

`static stack : TunSmolStack = TunSmolStack{ sockets: SocketSet::new(vec![]) }; `

does not have the issue.

Comment: Turns out `From` in `ManagedSlice` requires the variable to be static. Are you sure your explanation for the `static` lifetime choice from the compiler is right? Take a look: https://docs.rs/managed/0.7.1/src/managed/slice.rs.html#74-78. This was fixed, I simply updated to a new version of `Managed` and the error gone away